# Blender how to locate animation_data.action.fcurves

Tags: python, scripting, blender, add-on

How do i locate the action and fcurves of an animated `bpy.props.FloatProperty` contained in a class `bpy.types.PropertyGroup`.

i have the following class:

```
class STRUCT_t(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    Types = [
        ('NONE', "none", ""),
        ('POLAR', "Polar", ""),
        ('ORTHOGONAL', "Orthogonal", "")
    ]
    
    Type: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items = Types,
        name = "Type",
        description = "Type",
        default = 'POLAR'
    )
    
    scaleSeed: bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name="Scale Seed",
        description="Scale Seed",
        default=12345,
        min=0,
        soft_min=0,
        step=1,
        update=coordinates_update,
    )
```

Inside of blender i animated the seed using keyframes, normally i will be able to find the fcurves using the following line:

```
bpy.data.objects['objName'].animation_data.action.fcurves
```

but in this specific case the animation data is empty.

Is there another location that animation_data can be stored?

I also tried the following:

```
bpy.data.objects['objName'].data.shape_keys.animation_data.action.fcurves
```

Considering that the animation is not shape related it did not work.